# NSWorkspace setIcon:forFile:options: crashes

Tags: cocoa

I am facing crash sometimes on [NSWorkspace setIcon:forFile:options:] API.

any help is appreciated.
here is crash stack,

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bfbe56 __semwait_signal_nocancel + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c04818b nanosleep$NOCANCEL + 139
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8bfe7c78 usleep$NOCANCEL + 53
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8bfe7aa6 abort + 187
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c04684c free + 389
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x00007fff8df7aaf7 CSMemDisposePtr + 23
6   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x00007fff8df7aaba CSMemDisposeHandle + 79
7   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x00007fff8df7c355 DisposeHandle + 9
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90356598 -[NSWorkspace setIcon:forFile:options:] + 566
```

Here is code,

```
static NSImage  *FolderIcon = nil;

if(!FolderIcon) {
        FolderIcon = [[NSImage imageNamed:@"xxx.icns"] retain];
}

if(![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon: FolderIcon
                                       forFile:Path
                                       options:0]) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}
```

I am using static icon, so I don't think possibility of dangling pointer, Also I checked if we pass file path which does not exists then it return "NO". But it is not crashing.

This is rarely re-producible.. will paste errors once it re-produce

Comment: There should also have been an error written to the console log.  Add that.  That said, it looks like a memory management bug.  You have probably passed in a dangling pointer to a deallocated object.

Comment: Please show us the actual code you are using that causes the crash as well as any other messages in the logger. Any warnings when you compile?

Comment: Also, please show us the code that creates or obtains the image object.

Comment: This is most likely a memory management mistake on your part. Try switching to the modern API to see if you get any different results (-[NSURL setResourceValue:forKey:error:])

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `-setIcon:forFile:options:` from multiple thread at a time.

From [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/setIcon:forFile:options:):

> It is safe to call this method from any of your app’s threads, but you
>   must call it from only one thread at a time.